# Как задать таймаут для синхронной функции connect?

Tags: c++, c, windows, сеть, сокет

Если для функций `recv` и `send` таймаут ожидания задается через:

```
DWORD timeout = 5000;
setsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
setsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

то как правильно задать таймаут для синхронной функции [connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx)?

p.s. по тестам, даже при заданном в реестре (минимально возможном) параметре `TcpTimedWaitDelay` в `0x0000001e (30)` ожидание функции занимает примерно секунд 20.

Comment: Синхронный connect этого вроде не умеет, лучше используйте асинхронный вариант: [How to set a socket connection timeout](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/168704/How-to-set-a-socket-connection-timeout)

Comment: @mega, так и поступил, благодарю.

Answer (score -4):

Вообще-то для `SO_SNDTIMEO` и `SO_RCVTIMEO` время передается через структуру `timeval`:

```
struct timeval{
    long tv_sec;   // seconds
    long tv_usec;  // and microseconds
};
```

Вот в нее надо записать соответствующие значения и передать ее адрес в качестве четвертого параметра.

Comment: MSDN с вами не согласен. Приведите источник, где написано про timeval

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Скажите, где говорилось, что речь идет о Visual Studio? Windows - это не только Visual Studio. Это еще и GCC, например.

Comment: @Mikhailo, а по Вашему, значит, `setsockopt` примет `timeval` если его компилировать GCC? Вопрос про `windows`, так-то.

Comment: @mega Ну, если вы даже не знаете, что GCC вполне компилирует под Windows... :)

Comment: @Mikhailo, т.е. Вы даже не понимаете, что дело не в компиляторе?

Comment: @mega Ну вы даже не понимаете, что на самом деле используется timeval... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244082/proper-use-of-getsockopt-and-setsockopt-for-so-rcvtimeo-and-so-sndtimeo  http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?353217-example-of-SO_RCVTIMEO-using-setsockopt%28%29  https://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt  http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=41184  Но я понимаю, что вам хоть кол на голове теши - если ослик упрется, то его не сдвинуть :) Так что я зря тут мечу бисер...

Comment: Хотя бы по своим же ссылкам почитайте: "**WINDOWS:** 
Timeout value is a DWORD in milliseconds, address passed to setsockopt() is const char * **LINUX:**
Timeout value is a struct timeval, address passed to setsockopt() is const void *".