# Какой тип имеют параметры SO_SNDTIMEO и SO_RCVTIMEO для Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, сокет

Какой тип имеют параметры `SO_SNDTIMEO` и `SO_RCVTIMEO`, которые задаются в [setsockopt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) для Windows?

Я всегда считал что `DWORD`, пример:

```
DWORD timeout = 5000;
setsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
setsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

Но смутил меня [этот ответ.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/692967) Я предложил правку, ее отклонили. Гуру, поясните ситуацию.

Comment: Не помешала бы и ссылка на отклонённую правку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN по ссылке https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx четко говорит, что это DWORD

"SO_SNDTIMEO - DWORD - The timeout, in milliseconds, for blocking send calls." - цитата из MSDN

Comment: Минимальную выдержку в ответе тоже было бы хорошо привести.